# missing SHIPTONAME array element in Paypal GetExpressCheckoutDetails response in Magento 1.14

Tags: php, magento, paypal

We are experiencing an inconsistent but frequent (approx one per day) issue where the response from the GetExpressCheckoutDetails call is missing the `SHIPTONAME` and `PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTONAME` array elements. All other `SHIP...` and `PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIP...` values are present. Here is a snippet of an example response:

```
        [FIRSTNAME] => Redacted
        [LASTNAME] => Redacted
        [COUNTRYCODE] => AU
        [SHIPTOSTREET] => 29 Redacted Road
        [SHIPTOCITY] => Redacted Town
        [SHIPTOSTATE] => New South Wales
        [SHIPTOZIP] => 2321
        [SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE] => AU
...
        [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT] => 9.05
        [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_HANDLINGAMT] => 0.00
        [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT] => 19.06
        [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET] => 29 Redacted Road
        [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCITY] => Redacted Town
        [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTATE] => New South Wales
        [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOZIP] => 2321
        [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE] => AU
```

The customer has supplied screenshots from their Paypal account to demonstrate that a shipping name (and address) was supplied. We can't reproduce this issue. Any pointer appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently this is an issue with Paypal itself. We received the following response:

> My name is REDACTED from PayPal merchant technical support. I understand that you are having a problem missing SHIPTONAME value and that causing you unable to supplied shipping information to your client. At the meantime, this issue was a well known issue at our end and we're still collecting data to resolve this issue. I will get back to you and give you an update once this problem solve by our developers. I apologize for any inconvenience caused.
>
> Merchant Technical Support
>
> PayPal, an eBay Company

Answer (score 2):

We had the very same issue confirmed by Paypal.  They said they rolled out a fix today for it. (07/07/2015 02:15 PM EST)
" 
I have received word from our engineers that a correction has been made live for the bug that causes the SHIPTONAME to not be included. "